# Is "inline" any good for normal function in kotlin

Tags: function, kotlin, jvm

I came to know the benefit of inline in higher order function in case of performanec

like :

```
inline fun adder(x:Int,y:Int,(Int,Int)->Int){
// do something
}
```

in this case compiler virtually copies the code at the calling place of adder() function at runtime. Which results in better performance .

but is inline be useful for regular function
like::

```
inline fun sum(x:Int,y:Int):Int {
}
```

is there any benefit of using inline in sum function

Answer (score 1):

This is briefly touched on in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html), where it says:

> If an inline function has no inlinable function parameters and no reified type parameters, the compiler will issue a warning, since inlining such functions is very unlikely to be beneficial.

The warning produced by the compiler when you mark a normal function inline is as follows ([source](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/68af7056642048bb0855d31aa6b5d0ce1953ebd0/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/diagnostics/rendering/DefaultErrorMessages.java#L1253C37-L1253C166)):

> Expected performance impact from inlining is insignificant. Inlining works best for functions with parameters of functional types.

However, there have been some suggestions that this warning should be removed or weakened, since inline functions can be useful for other reasons.

For example, there's an open issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16769 which suggests a couple of possible reasons to make functions inline. For example, an inline function could be used as an "alias" for another function, if you just want to refer to it by a different name or refine its type signature.